# gcc and intel's icpc on redhat do not recognize namespace std::literals;

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++14, icc

I get an error that ‘literals’ is not a namespace-name when compiling the following

```
#include <complex>
using namespace std::literals;
...
```

its compiles fine on Windows with MSVC and even on OS X with clang, but fails on redhat 7 using either gcc and intel's icpc.

> some more detail:
>
> the system

```
 cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

> gcc version

```
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

> Intel compiler version

```
icpc --version
icpc (ICC) 16.0.3 20160415
Copyright (C) 1985-2016 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

> compiler call

```
gcc filename.cpp -std=c++1y
icpc filename.cpp -std=c++14
```

what am I missing?

ps: Even simple code like [in this live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8ca9c050e0a9673) doesn't work:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libstdc++ that comes with GCC 4.8.x does not have those literals; [they started shipping beginning with GCC 4.9.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html).